# Simple Python Nest For Loop Exhausts Memory

Tags: python, out-of-memory, csc

I have a list of quadruples which is read from a CSV file, with element of the form t =(id, e1, e2, label). The list should contain for every t, the tuple: (someID, e2,e1, 3-label). If not, I need to add to the list.

I have written the following code and narrowed down my list to only 50 tuples.

```
import nltk
import csv
#file string
fs = "mydataset.csv"
with open(fs) as infile:
    rows = list(csv.reader(infile))[950:1000]
    size = len(rows)
    print("initial size =", size)
    newSize = size
    firstId = int(rows[1][0])
    lastId = int(rows[size-1][0])
    for i in range(size):
        if i % 500 == 0:
            rint("program progression = ", i*100/size, '%', sep ='')
        tempRow = rows[i]
        if tempRow[-1] == '1' or tempRow[-1] == '2':
                for j in range(i+1, size):
                # print("j = ", j)
                    if tempRow[1] == rows[j][2] and tempRow[2] == rows[j][1]:
                        if int(tempRow[3]) == 3-int(rows[j][3]):
                            break
                        else:
                            print("error in row: ", i)
                    else:
                        if j == size -1:
                            lastId +=1
                            print(tempRow[-1])
                            rows += rows +[[ str(lastId), tempRow[2], tempRow[1], str(3-int(tempRow[3])) ]]
                            newSize +=1
                            print("newSize", newSize)
    print("END")
```

When I run this, it exhausts my memory. It uses over 8GB of memory? What is going on please? My CSC file has only 7200 rows with 4 columns. I really don't know what else I should do.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know, but this line looks highly suspect:

```
rows += rows +[[ str(lastId), tempRow[2], tempRow[1], str(3-int(tempRow[3])) ]]
```

I can't guess what you're *trying* to do here, but it's very unlikely this line implements your intent.  This more than *doubles* the length of `rows` each time it's executed, and there doesn't appear to be anything in your code that reduces the length of `rows`.

Making it really simple to get the point across:

```
>>> rows = [1]
>>> for i in range(20):
...     rows += rows
...     print(i, len(rows))
```

displays:

```
0 2
1 4
2 8
3 16
4 32
5 64
6 128
7 256
8 512
9 1024
10 2048
11 4096
12 8192
13 16384
14 32768
15 65536
16 131072
17 262144
18 524288
19 1048576
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! You got it. I had to do remove +!

```
rows = rows +[[ str(lastId), tempRow[2], tempRow[1], str(3-int(tempRow[3])) ]]
```